# Visual Studio 2002: Microsoft support

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2002

Does any one know when Microsoft intends to stop supporting Visual Studio 2002?

Comment: ... and possibly a few upvotes on answers you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they [plan to stop support](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=Visual+Studio).

Pre-SP1 support is stopped.  SP1 end of life plan [is here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&x=7&y=9).

Answer (score 2):

It is covered by the Microsoft 5+5 support policy.  That means, 5 years mainstream support (ended in 2007), plus 5 years of "extended" support (you pay).  And after that, it's special bid only.